# view thumbnail link putting a 0 after my url when clicked - why?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I created this view with a thumbnail containing a link that leads to the full node. The URL to the full node is the name of the node with a 0 after it. For example instead of `localhost/sitename/name-of-the-node` the URL becomes `localhost/sitename/name-of-the-node-0`.

What shows up then is a sort of 'stripped' version of the full node where in my case the node title is missing, the full body text will show up but its hard to style with css and things are weird.

**note for moderators:** I posted this same question to drupal answers to contribute to making it active, but last question i posted in drupal answers it literally took 13 days before a response came, so I hope I can keep this question in SO as well because I'm a little (much :-)) pressed for time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the 0 in the URL comes when pathauto makes a URL out of a duplicate node title. Change nodetitle.